# What can I say about complexity of this optimisation problem?

Tags: time-complexity, optimization

I have a set of parameters $\{\alpha_s\}$, and I have $u$ functions of the form $w_i(\{\alpha_s\}) = \prod\alpha_s^{c^{i}_s} $ for some known values of $c^{i}_s$. Similarly, I have $b$ functions of the form $w^{ij}_l(\{\alpha_s\}) =\prod\alpha_s^{c^{ijl}_s} $. Now I
the following optimisation problem to be solved:

$$\text{maximise}_{{\{\alpha_s\}}} \sum_{i=1}^{u}k_i \log (w_i(\{\alpha_s\})) + \sum_{i\leq j}^{u}\sum_{l=1}^{b}h^{ij}_l\log(w^{ij}_l(\{\alpha_s\}))$$
Subject to
$$\sum_{i}w_i(\{\alpha_s\})) =1$$
$$\sum_{l}w^{ij}_l(\{\alpha_s\}) = 1$$
$$\alpha_s \geq 0$$

$\{k_i\}$ and $\{h^{ij}_l\}$ are some integer constants.

Can I say anything about the computational complexity of this problem ? Most of all I would like to know if I can clame it's polynomial in $\sum k_i + \sum h^{ij}_v$

Comment: $w^{ij}_l$ does not appear to depend on $l$.  Is that an error?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notion of "solving for" a Lagrange multiplier -- what does that mean?

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for the comments, $w^{ij}_l$ depends on $l$, I have made corresponding correction. Also, I have tried to make it clearer w.r.t your second comment, Pls. Let me know if it's still unclear :D

Comment: I suppose you know that if you write down a random optimization problem then its complexity is unlikely to be polynomial unless you happy to get lucky and there is some structure to exploit.  I don't see any reason to expect this problem to be solvable in polynomial time.  It's also ugly or messy enough that I am not optimistic you're going to get a clear answer one way or another.  I presume you already know that the objective function you are maximizing is a linear function of the $\alpha$'s, but the constraints are ugly.